# calculate distance between two place using latitude-longitude getting wrong distance in java

Tags: java

i am using haversine formula to calculate distance but i am getting wrong distance actually google map distance is 8.1km but haversine formula is showing 4.06

```
private static final int EARTH_RADIUS = 6371; // Approx Earth radius in KM

public static double distance(double startLat, double startLong, double endLat, double endLong) {

    double dLat = Math.toRadians((endLat - startLat));
    double dLong = Math.toRadians((endLong - startLong));

    startLat = Math.toRadians(startLat);
    endLat = Math.toRadians(endLat);

    double a = haversin(dLat) + Math.cos(startLat) * Math.cos(endLat) * haversin(dLong);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    return EARTH_RADIUS * c; // <-- d
}

public static double haversin(double val) {
    return Math.pow(Math.sin(val / 2), 2);
}
```

Comment: Your formula could be off, but first of all, is that Google Map's distance the point-to-point distance, or is it the distance travelled via streets/roads?  Note that the two would likely not always be the same.

Comment: Can you give inputs, expected output and actual output? Plus, shouldn't the earth radius be in meters instead of kilometers?

Comment: @sp00m if an answer in kilometres is required, you need to have the Earth's radius in kilometres.  If an answer in metres is required, you need to have the Earth's radius in metres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: actually i am suing in km but also not working

Comment: inputs of two distance(17.451955, 78.478187, 17.442504, 78.441323);

Comment: hi JssiV, i used same but it also showing same wrong distance

Answer (score 1):

### Your formula is correct, the problem come from bad use of google map

As suggested by Tim in comments, you need to see the point-to-point distance, not road distance

Using the two distance(17.451955, 78.478187, 17.442504, 78.441323) give 4.06km:

[image: map]

8.1km is probably the distance by road, and not point-to-point

Comment: Don't you said that you had 4.06 km using the formula?

Comment: actually i need to get near restaurants based on save restaurants with lat and long in database with current lat and long..if i use google api for one rest lat and lon its fine,but if i need to compare 50 restaurants,it is not good to

Comment: when i am using above code i am getting different distance which is not not same distance google map

Comment: I just test it, java code give me 4.04925264532218. They are not *exact* same distances, but both google map and your code give us 4.05km, isn't that what you want?

Comment: hi Kepotx, actually distance is 8 km but showing 4.04km

Comment: point to point distance is 4.05km. If you want road distance, you can't use haversine formula